# Unable to capture data in QT using TCP Sockets from non QT application

Tags: c++, qt

I have created one server in my QT application and client in non-qt application.

Code of my server in QT application is goes as below

```
#ifndef MMI_TCPSERVER_H
#define MMI_TCPSERVER_H

#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include "MMISimForm.h"

class MyTcpServer : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
     MyTcpServer(MMISimForm *simForm, int portNo);
     void startServer();

private:
    int portNo_;
    MMISimForm* simForm_;
    QTcpSocket *socket;

    void OnConnected();

protected:
    void incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor);

public slots:
    void OnReadyRead();
    void OnDisconnected();
};

#endif

#include "MyTcpServer.h"

MyTcpServer::MyTcpServer(MMISimForm *simForm, int portNo) :
    simForm_(simForm), portNo_(portNo)
{
    portNo_ = portNo;
}


void MyTcpServer::startServer()
{
    if(!this->listen(QHostAddress::Any, portNo_))
    {
        //qDebug() << "Could not start server";
    }
    else
    {
        //qDebug() << "Listening to port " << portNo_ << "...";
    }
}

void MyTcpServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket();

    // set the ID
    if(!socket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor))
    {
        //OnErrorSocket(socket->error());
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        simForm_->logMessage("Server Started");
        socket->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::KeepAliveOption, 1);
        //OnConnected();
    }

    // connect socket and signal
    // note - Qt::DirectConnection is used because it's multithreaded
    //        This makes the slot to be invoked immediately, when the signal is emitted.
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(OnReadyRead()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(OnDisconnected()));
}


// TcpServer
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Reads incoming TCH command
void MyTcpServer::OnReadyRead()
{
    const QString cmdStr(socket->readAll());
    simForm_->logMessage("Server Started");

}

void MyTcpServer::OnDisconnected()
{
    simForm_->logMessage("Server Closed");
}
```

and client code goes in my non-qt application

```
#include "ServerSocket.h"
ServerSocket::ServerSocket()
{
    WSAStartup(0x0101, &w) != 0;
    /* Open a datagram socket */
    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    /* Clear out server struct */
    memset((void *)&server, '\0', sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(5000);
    server.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    connect(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
}
```

And I have one send function which send data to server as

```
int ServerSocket::sendData()
{
   send(sd , "hello" , strlen("hello") , 0 );
}
```

I have checked the return value of send function it comes as 5 means data bytes are sent correctly.

But readyRead signal is not emitted.Hence I am not able to capture data in QT.

What wrong I am doing? QT GUI event loop is running correctly (app:exec()).

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] if possible.  Is `MyTcpServer::incomingConnection` called as expected?  You also mention threading (in a code comment) which could be relevant.

Comment: @G.M. I am not using thread that is  previously I have written but I am not using any threading.

Simply establishing  TCP connection between two process. TCP Server code is in QT application side and Client is in non qt application.

The problem is readyRead signal is not emitted.

Or do you have some example reference which you can share to establish two way communication between QT application and Non qt application. Both application will only run in same computer.

Comment: You haven't answered my question though.  Is `MyTcpServer::incomingConnection` called as expected?

Comment: @G.M. Yes it is called fine.